# Use of if clause in OpenMP

Tags: synchronization, task, openmp

Can't figure out the use of the if (0) clause in the following code as there also exists the #pragma omp single clause. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for the definitions from [Specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) (which I assume you know):

> When an if clause is present on a task construct, and the if clause  expression evaluates to false, an undeferred task is generated, and the encountering thread must suspend the current task region, for which execution cannot be resumed until the generated task is completed.

Where an undeferred task is defined as:

> A task for which execution is not deferred with respect to its generating task region. That is, its generating task region is suspended until execution of the undeferred task is completed.

And from general task description:

> The encountering thread may immediately execute the task, or defer its execution. In the latter case, any thread in the team may be assigned the task.

Which in general brings me to the conclusion that as you stated there would be the same outcome as not using the `if(0)`. But as I understand what the `undeferred` means is that the generated task is called immeadiately by the thread that creates it.

Which in this context ensures that the tasks A() to C() are created in "one" step without context switching or else in between, by assigning the task to a previously idle thread.